# Consequences of a function being twice differentiable

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f : \mathbb R^2 → \mathbb R$ be a function that lies in $C^2(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb R)$.

Assume that
$f(0, 0) = \frac{∂f}{∂x}(0, 0) = \frac{∂f}{∂y}(0, 0) = 1$.

Assume also that lim$_{||(x,y)||_2→∞} $ $\frac{f(x,y)}{||(x,y)||_2^2} = 0$.

Show that there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that for all $(x, y) ∈ \mathbb R^2$

$|f(x, y) − (1 + x + y)| ≤ C(x^2 + y^2)$

My attempt:

Since $f(0, 0) = \frac{∂f}{∂x}(0, 0) = \frac{∂f}{∂y}(0, 0) = 1$, then $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ and $f$ converges to $1$, i.e. for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta >0$ s.t if $|(x, y)-(0,0)| < \delta$, then $|f(x, y) - f(0,0)| < \epsilon$. Thus, $|f(x, y) - 1|<\epsilon$

I am also given that $f$ is twice differentiable in $\mathbb R^2$, thus for all $v_0 \in \mathbb R^2$, we have:

Lim$_{v→v_0}$ $\frac{||D_vf - D_{v_0}f - D_{v_0}^2f||}{||v-v_0||} = 0$, where $v:=(x, y) $ and $v_0 := (0,0)$. Hence,

Lim$_{(x, y) →(0,0)}$ $\frac{||D_{(x,y)}f - D_{(0,0)}f - D_{(0,0)}^2f||}{||(x,y)||_2} = 0$, i.e. for all $\epsilon$'$>0$, there exists $\delta$'$>0$ s.t if $|(x, y)| < \delta$', then $\frac{|D_{(x,y)}f - D_{(0,0)}f - D_{(0,0)}^2f|}{||(x,y)||_2} < \epsilon$', hence ${|D_{(x,y)}f - D_{(0,0)}f - D_{(0,0)}^2f|} < \epsilon$'$||(x,y)||_2$

And I know that $||f||_{C^2(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb R)}$ = sup$_{(x, y) \not= 0}$ $\frac{||f.(x,y)||}{||(x, y)||}$

And so, ${||D_{(x,y)}f - D_{(0,0)}f - D_{(0,0)}^2f||}$ = sup$_{k\not= 0} $ $\frac{|D_{(x,y)}f - D_{(0,0)}f - D_{(0,0)}^2f|.k}{||k||_2}$, where $k \in \mathbb R^2$

But then how do I continue from there? I'm stuck. Please any help?

Comment: Knowing $lim_{||(x,y)||_2\to\infty}\frac{f(x,y)}{||(x,y)||_2^2}=0$ implies that for all $N>0$ there exists $R>0$ such that $||(x,y)||_2\geq R$ implies $|frac{f(x,y)}{||(x,y)||_2^2}|\leq N$. in particular, since we must have $frac{f(x,y)-1-x-y}{||(x,y)||_2^2}\to 0$, and so we can say there exists $R>0$ such that $|f(x,y)-1-x-y|\leq ||(x,y)||_2^2=x^2+y^2$ for all $||(x,y)||_2\geq R$. So you just need to show $frac{f(x,y)-1-x-y}{||(x,y)||_2^2}$ is bounded on the compact disc $||(x,y)||_2\leq R$. What you've done should shows it's bounded near 0, and hence bounded in any disc containing 0

Comment: Could you please edit your comment so that I can read better? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't fit this into a comment, but it's not quite an answer

Knowing

$$lim_{||(x,y)||_2\to\infty}\frac{f(x,y)}{||(x,y)||_2^2}=0$$

means that for all $N>0$ there exists $R>0$ such that $||(x,y)||_2\geq R$ implies $$|\frac{f(x,y)}{||(x,y)||_2^2}|\leq N$$.

Since $\frac{1+x+y}{||(x,y)||_2^2}$ will also tend to 0, we have that
$$\frac{f(x,y)-1-x-y}{||(x,y)||_2^2}\to 0$$

We can take $N=1$ and so there exists $R>0$ such that $$|f(x,y)-1-x-y|\leq ||(x,y)||_2^2=x^2+y^2$$ for all $||(x,y)||_2\geq R$.

So we have the inequality for $||(x,y)_2||$ big enough.

You just need to show $\frac{f(x,y)-1-x-y}{||(x,y)||_2^2}$ is bounded on the compact disc $||(x,y)||_2\leq R$. To do so, it is sufficient to show that it is continuous on this disc. It is clearly continuous away from $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Can you use what you have done to show that

$$lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-1-x-y}{||(x,y)||_2^2}$$

exists?

Comment: Which part of what I've done can shiw that the limit as you said in your answer exists?

Comment: Where you have considered a second derivative, instead consider a first derivative. We know $$lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}||f(x,y) - f(0,0)-D_{(0,0)}f||/||(x,y)||=0$$. Here $D_{(0,0)}f=\partial_xf(0,0)x+\partial_yf(0,0)y=x+y$.